# Cross-referencing to self-made counters in Alignat environment

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I am using the `alignat` environment for equations. Now, I want to refer to some places in this environment. I have made a counter to do so.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\newcommand{\scounter}{\newcounter{ct} \setcounter{ct}{0}}
\newcommand{\pcounter}{\refstepcounter{ct} \arabic{ct}}


\begin{document}

\scounter
\begin{alignat*}{20}
& \text{First object: } \pcounter. \label{one}\\
& \text{Second object: } \pcounter. \label{two} \\
\end{alignat*}

Now I want to reference to the first object: \ref{one}.
\end{document}
```

Latex does not give the reference, although it does give the following Error: `Multiple \label's: label 'one' will be lost \end{alignat}`.

Can anyone tell me how to make the referencing work?

Thanks!

P.S. I do not want to use the regular referencing method (with the equation numbers displayed at the right of every line). This is because I want to display the values of the counter above  equality signs, using `\stackrel`.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not modify the way the equation numbers are printed?

It suffices to change the original definition of `amsmath` adding these lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces$\stackrel{#1}{=}$\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces$\stackrel{#1}{=}$\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{20}
& \text{First object: } . \label{one}\\
& \text{Second object: } . \label{two}
\end{alignat}

Now I want to reference to the first object: \ref{one}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]